# Terraform Azure Databricks Provider Error

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks

I need some assistance to undertand the various forms of logging in to Databricks. I am using Terraform to provision Azure Databricks
I would like to know the difference in the two codes below
When i use option 1, i get the error as shown

Option 1:

```
  required_providers {
    azuread     = "~> 1.0"
    azurerm     = "~> 2.0"
    azuredevops = { source = "registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops", version = "~> 0.0" }
    databricks  = { source = "registry.terraform.io/databrickslabs/databricks", version = "~> 0.0" }
  }
}

provider "random" {}
provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id     = var.project.arm.tenant.id
  client_id     = var.project.arm.client.id
  client_secret = var.secret.arm.client.secret
}

provider "databricks" {
  host          = azurerm_databricks_workspace.db-workspace.workspace_url
  azure_use_msi = true
}

resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "db-workspace" {
  name                          = module.names-db-workspace.environment.databricks_workspace.name_unique
  resource_group_name           = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  location                      = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  sku                           = "premium"
  public_network_access_enabled = true

  custom_parameters {
    no_public_ip                                         = true
    virtual_network_id                                   = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.self.id
    public_subnet_name                                   = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.subnets["db-sub-1-public"].name
    private_subnet_name                                  = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.subnets["db-sub-2-private"].name
    public_subnet_network_security_group_association_id  = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.nsgs.associations.subnets["databricks-public-nsg-db-sub-1-public"].id
    private_subnet_network_security_group_association_id = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.nsgs.associations.subnets["databricks-private-nsg-db-sub-2-private"].id
  }
  tags = local.tags
}
```

## Databricks Cluster Creation

```
resource "databricks_cluster" "dbcselfservice" {
  cluster_name            = format("adb-cluster-%s-%s", var.project.name, var.project.environment.name)
  spark_version           = var.spark_version
  node_type_id            = var.node_type_id
  autotermination_minutes = 20
  autoscale {
    min_workers = 1
    max_workers = 7
  }
  azure_attributes {
    availability       = "SPOT_AZURE"
    first_on_demand    = 1
    spot_bid_max_price = 100
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.db-workspace
  ]
}
```

## Databricks Workspace RBAC Permission

```
resource "databricks_group" "db-group" {
  display_name               = format("adb-users-%s", var.project.name)
  allow_cluster_create       = true
  allow_instance_pool_create = true
  depends_on = [
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.db-workspace
  ]
}

resource "databricks_user" "dbuser" {
  count            = length(local.display_name)
  display_name     = local.display_name[count.index]
  user_name        = local.user_name[count.index]
  workspace_access = true
  depends_on = [
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.db-workspace
  ]
}
```

## Adding Members to Databricks Admin Group

```
resource "databricks_group_member" "i-am-admin" {
  for_each  = toset(local.email_address)
  group_id  = data.databricks_group.admins.id
  member_id = databricks_user.dbuser[index(local.email_address, each.key)].id
  depends_on = [
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.db-workspace
  ]
}

data "databricks_group" "admins" {
  display_name = "admins"
  depends_on = [
    #    resource.databricks_cluster.dbcselfservice,
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.db-workspace
  ]
}
```

The error that i get while TF apply is below :

```
Error: User not authorized

with databricks_user.dbuser[1],
on resources.adb.tf line 80, in resource "databricks_user" "dbuser":
80: resource "databricks_user" "dbuser"{


Error: User not authorized

with databricks_user.dbuser[0],
on resources.adb.tf line 80, in resource "databricks_user" "dbuser":
80: resource "databricks_user" "dbuser"{

Error: cannot refresh AAD token: adal:Refresh request failed. Status Code =  '500'. Response body: {"error":"server_error", "error_description":"Internal server error"} Endpoint http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F

with databricks_group.db-group,
on resources.adb.tf line 80, in resource "databricks_group" "db-group":
71: resource "databricks_group" "db-group"{
```

Is the error coming because of this block below ?

```
provider "databricks" {
  host          = azurerm_databricks_workspace.db-workspace.workspace_url
  azure_use_msi = true
}
```

I just need to login automatically when i click on the URL from the portal. So what shall i use for that? And why do we need to provide two times databricks providers, once under required_providers and again in provider "databricks"?
I have seen if i don't provide the second provider i get the error :

```
"authentication is not configured for provider"
```

Comment: Hello @Pallab, May I know how you are authenticating for azurerm provider?? if you are using az login then you don't have to use `azure_use_msi = true`. You can remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments , If you are using Azure CLI authentication i.e. `az login` using your username and password , then you can use the below code :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    databricks = {
      source = "databrickslabs/databricks"
      version = "0.3.11"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
provider "databricks" {
    host = azurerm_databricks_workspace.example.workspace_url
}

resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "example" {
  name                        = "DBW-ansuman"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                         = "premium"
  managed_resource_group_name = "ansuman-DBW-managed-without-lb"

  public_network_access_enabled = true

  custom_parameters {
    no_public_ip        = true
    public_subnet_name  = azurerm_subnet.public.name
    private_subnet_name = azurerm_subnet.private.name
    virtual_network_id  = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id

    public_subnet_network_security_group_association_id  = azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.public.id
    private_subnet_network_security_group_association_id = azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.private.id
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
    Pricing     = "Standard"
  }
}
data "databricks_node_type" "smallest" {
  local_disk = true
    depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}
data "databricks_spark_version" "latest_lts" {
  long_term_support = true
    depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}
resource "databricks_cluster" "dbcselfservice" {
  cluster_name            = "Shared Autoscaling"
  spark_version           = data.databricks_spark_version.latest_lts.id
  node_type_id            = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
  autotermination_minutes = 20
  autoscale {
    min_workers = 1
    max_workers = 7
  }
  azure_attributes {
    availability       = "SPOT_AZURE"
    first_on_demand    = 1
    spot_bid_max_price = 100
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}
resource "databricks_group" "db-group" {
  display_name               = "adb-users-admin"
  allow_cluster_create       = true
  allow_instance_pool_create = true
  depends_on = [
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}

resource "databricks_user" "dbuser" {
  display_name     = "Rahul Sharma"
  user_name        = "example@contoso.com"
  workspace_access = true
  depends_on = [
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}
resource "databricks_group_member" "i-am-admin" {
  group_id  = databricks_group.db-group.id
  member_id = databricks_user.dbuser.id
  depends_on = [
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

If you are using `Service Principal` as authentication , then you can use something like below:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    databricks = {
      source = "databrickslabs/databricks"
      version = "0.3.11"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "948d4068-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e00a844e059b"
  tenant_id = "72f988bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2d7cd011db47"
  client_id = "f6a2f33d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d713a1bb37c0"
  client_secret = "inl7Q~Gvdxxxx-xxxx-xxxxyaGPF3uSoL"
  features {}
}
provider "databricks" {
    host = azurerm_databricks_workspace.example.workspace_url
    azure_client_id = "f6a2f33d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d713a1bb37c0"
    azure_client_secret = "inl7Q~xxxx-xxxx-xxxxg6ntiyaGPF3uSoL"
    azure_tenant_id = "72f988bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2d7cd011db47"
}


resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "example" {
  name                        = "DBW-ansuman"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                         = "premium"
  managed_resource_group_name = "ansuman-DBW-managed-without-lb"

  public_network_access_enabled = true

  custom_parameters {
    no_public_ip        = true
    public_subnet_name  = azurerm_subnet.public.name
    private_subnet_name = azurerm_subnet.private.name
    virtual_network_id  = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id

    public_subnet_network_security_group_association_id  = azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.public.id
    private_subnet_network_security_group_association_id = azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.private.id
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
    Pricing     = "Standard"
  }
}
data "databricks_node_type" "smallest" {
  local_disk = true
    depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}
data "databricks_spark_version" "latest_lts" {
  long_term_support = true
    depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}
resource "databricks_cluster" "dbcselfservice" {
  cluster_name            = "Shared Autoscaling"
  spark_version           = data.databricks_spark_version.latest_lts.id
  node_type_id            = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
  autotermination_minutes = 20
  autoscale {
    min_workers = 1
    max_workers = 7
  }
  azure_attributes {
    availability       = "SPOT_AZURE"
    first_on_demand    = 1
    spot_bid_max_price = 100
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}
resource "databricks_group" "db-group" {
  display_name               = "adb-users-admin"
  allow_cluster_create       = true
  allow_instance_pool_create = true
  depends_on = [
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}

resource "databricks_user" "dbuser" {
  display_name     = "Rahul Sharma"
  user_name        = "example@contoso.com"
  workspace_access = true
  depends_on = [
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}
resource "databricks_group_member" "i-am-admin" {
  group_id  = databricks_group.db-group.id
  member_id = databricks_user.dbuser.id
  depends_on = [
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.example
  ]
}
```

---

> And why do we need to provide
> two times databricks providers, once under required_providers and
> again in provider "databricks"?

The `required_providers` is used to download and initialize the required providers from the source i.e. `Terraform Registry` . But the `Provider Block` is used for further configuration of that downloaded provider like describing client_id, features block etc. which can be used for authentication or other configuration.

Comment: We deploy our development environment locally with az login. The rest is done through service principals. How can we support both? This has worked in the past with specifying only the host, but not anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The `azure_use_msi` option is primarily intended for use from CI/CD pipelines that are executed on machines with [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/) assigned to them. All possible authentication options are described in the [documenation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs#authentication), but simplest way is to use [authentication via Azure CLI](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs#authenticating-with-azure-cli), so you just need to leave `host` parameter in the provider block.  If you don't have Azure CLI on that machine, you can use combination of [host + personal access token](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs#authenticating-with-hostname-and-token) instead.

if you're running that code from the machine with assigned managed identity, then you need to make sure that this identity is either added into workspace, or it has Contributor access to it - see [Azure Databricks documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#--get-an-azure-active-directory-access-token) for more details.